# .net 4 and Sharepoint Server 2007 on same server

Tags: .net-4.0, sharepoint-2007, windows-server-2003

My situation is that I developed a .NET 4 based MVC2 web app, and now I have to deploy it on a  Windows Server 2003 that has standalone SharePoint 2007 living on it. My quick research shows that SharePoint 2007 [doesn't play with .NET 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889408/can-i-use-net-4-with-sharepoint-2007). So my questions are:

1) Will SharePoint 2007 break if I install .NET 4 on the server? As far as I know .NET versions were backwards compatible...

2) Is it possible to deploy the .NET 4 assemblies with my web app without actually installing the framework and registering it.

3) Any other tips and advises on resolving this situation?

Comment: Sounds like a great question to ask on http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com !

Comment: @p.campbell Thank you sir for pointing me to that site, I am still not used to the multitude of stackexchange sites... However I'd still really like to have this question open here, since the chances of resolving it are better here, also it is development related. I don't think Sharepoint experts are the ones to ask about resolving .NET dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint wont'break if you apply latest service packs + cumulative updates to it.
At least I have such a combination running on my servers right now.

It would be a problem, if you tried installing .Net4.0 on the same machine prior to "Infrastructure update" of 2009 (or maybe before SP2?), since, as it was said "SharePoint stored some references to .net4 classes in the configuration database", whatever that means.